# Svg image mask cut top and bottom

Tags: html, css, svg, mask

I need to create images with this shape:
http://imgh.us/image-mask_1.svg

First i try with css mask but the problem was support of browsers. So i jump over to svg image with mask inside.

I have a problem with SVG image where top and bottom part of the mask is cut off.

I have created a codepen to show you the problem:

```
<svg width="551" height="397" viewBox="0 0 551 397">
  <defs>
    <mask id="section_mask">
      <image x="0.5" y="0.5" width="551" height="397" xlink:href="http://imgh.us/image-mask.svg" />
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <image mask="url(#section_mask)" width="551" height="397" xlink:href="http://imgh.us/kh110512-22049-1-1024x682.jpg" />
</svg>

http://codepen.io/lasse_head/pen/ObJLKN
```

Thanks Lasse

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the masked image has wrong width/height ratio.
The original image is 1024 x 682. The ration is 1.71788413. So, if you want to have height 397px, the width should be 397 x 1.71788413 = 596px . However, you set it to 551px.That was the reason for cutting.

```
<svg width="551" height="397" viewBox="0 0 551 397">
  <defs>
    <mask id="section_mask">
      <image x="0.5" y="0.5" width="551" height="397" xlink:href="http://imgh.us/image-mask.svg" />
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <image mask="url(#section_mask)" width="551" height="397" xlink:href="http://imgh.us/kh110512-22049-1-1024x682.jpg" />
</svg>
```